# why mongoose populate() request does not work?

Tags: mongodb, express

I try to populate some data from other collection to an other collection.i had googled the search and also i follow the tutorial step by step but the population had fail.any help is appreciate friends. this is the code:

```
router.get("/", passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false}), (req, res)=> {
  const errors = {};
  Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id})
  .then(profile => {
    if (!profile) {
      
      errors.noprofile = "there is no profile for this user"
    return res.status(404).json(errors);
    }
     res.json(profile);
  }).catch(err=> res.status(404).json(err))
});

// @route POST api/profile
//@desc Create or edit user profile
//@access Private

router.get("/", passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false}), (req, res)=> {

  const {errors, isValid} = validateProfileInput(req.body);
//Check validation
if(!isValid) {
  return res.status(400).json(errors);
}

  // Get profile data
const profileData = {};
  profileData.user = req.user.id;
  if(req.body.handle) {
     profileData.handle = req.body.handle
     
  };
  if(req.body.company) { 
    profileData.company = req.body.company
  };
  if(req.body.website) { 
    profileData.website = req.body.website
  };
  if(req.body.location) { 
    profileData.location = req.body.location
  };
  if(req.body.status) { 
    profileData.status = req.body.status
  };
  if(typeof req.body.skills !== 'undefined') {
    profileData.skills = req.body.skills.split(',');
  }

  //social
  profileData.social = {};
  if(req.body.youtube) { 
    profileData.social.youtube = req.body.youtube
  };
  if(req.body.twitter) { 
    profileData.social.twitter = req.body.twitter
  };
  if(req.body.facebook) { 
    profileData.social.facebook = req.body.facebook
  };
  if(req.body.instagram) { 
    profileData.social.instagram = req.body.instagram
  }; 
   
     Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id})
     .populate(
      
        
          "user",
          ["name, avatar"]
          
       
      
      
)
```

this is the result that I get from the postman :

"_id": "62ee1058ceb295ccdfedffce",
"user": "62e6825958870d3db69d2da5",
"handle": "pablo",
"status": "developper",
"skills": [
"design web"
],
and the correct result must be :

"_id": "62ee1058ceb295ccdfedffce",
"user": {"_id": "62e6825958870d3db69d2da5",
"name": "pablo",
"avatar": "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/1ffsrenbdgeajks-ghsdereys1dkkdhddbc"
}

```
"handle": "pablo",
"status": "developper",
"skills": [
    "design web"
],
```

Comment: What do your schema's look like?

Comment: it's too long my friend.I can't write in comment

Comment: let's pass to chat together